# Separate 1 column into 4

Tags: sql-server, split

I'm using SQL Server and I need a query that separates one column into 4 columns.

As you can see below, I have `ID` and `ADDINFO`; I want the split `ADDINFO` into 4 separate columns.

So # meaning new column

```
+==================================+======================================================================+==+
|                ID                |                               ADDINFO                                |  |
+==================================+======================================================================+==+
| 178                              | spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1993-01-29 00:00:00.000#PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 0 |  |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| 179                              | spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1993-01-29 00:00:00.000PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 0 |  |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| 180                              | spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1995-04-01 00:00:00.000#PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 1 |  |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| This is a row with only one cell |                                                                      |  |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

I want the table to look like this so the first field value will be upto # and the the next will start after # and end before #

does anyone know the best way of doing this as small will have null values in them too.

```
+==================================+======================================================================+========+=========================+===========+===========+
|                ID                |                               ADDINFO                                | spsDAR |         Barber          | PrevFMNRA | PreSReval |
+==================================+======================================================================+========+=========================+===========+===========+
| 178                              | spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1993-01-29 00:00:00.000#PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 0 |     50 | 1993-01-29 00:00:00.000 |        60 | 0|
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 179                              | spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1993-01-29 00:00:00.000#PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 0 |     50 | 1993-01-29 00:00:00.000 |        60 | 0      |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 180                              | spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1995-04-01 00:00:00.000PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 1 |     50 | 1995-04-01 00:00:00.000 |        60 | 1         |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| This is a row with only one cell |                                                                      |        |                         |           |           |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: What string functions have you looked at so far?

Answer (score 0):

You must write a Sql function which can return data in format
stringsplit(data,seperator,index)
and use select stringsplit(ADDINFO ,'#',1) from table;
if you just have maximum of 4 separator you can use PARSENAME function.

```
SELECT id,
     REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(ADDINFO ), '#', '.'), 1)) AS [Street]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(ADDINFO ), '#', '.'), 2)) AS [City]
   , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(ADDINFO ), '#', '.'), 3)) AS [State]
FROM dbo.table;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for this does do what i need but if its not a whole number is leaves the field as null e.g if the first column has 52.2 it will not return the values, and is there also a way to remove the heading of the values in the field for example the also need removing ,spsDAR:     #Barber:                                    #PrevFMNRA:    #Pre97XSReval:                                              ,spsDAR: 50#Barber: 1995-04-01 00:00:00.000#PrevFMNRA: 60#Pre97XSReval: 1                i just want the values after : as you can see above thanks